# How to pass an id of item from child component to parent?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, axios

I have a child component where creates a table. In this table I have in each row some data, delete and modify icons. When I click for example on delete icon, I need to pass an id of this item to parent component, where function will delete this item from database with axios. How can i provide this id?

Child:

```
import React from 'react';
import './tableHasp.css';


class TableHasp extends React.Component {
  render(){
    return(
      <tr>
         <td>{ this.props.hasps._id}</td>
         <td>{ this.props.hasps.serial }</td>
         <td>{ this.props.hasps.soft }</td>
         <td>{ this.props.hasps.numberOfKeys }</td>
         <td>{ this.props.hasps.company.name }</td>
         <td>{ this.props.hasps.company.city }</td>
         <td>{ this.props.hasps.company.phone }</td>
         <td>{ this.props.hasps.dateCreated }</td>
         <td><a href="#formId"><i onClick={this.props.modifyEvent} className="far fa-edit btnEdit"></i></a></td>
         <td><i  onClick={this.props.delEvent} className="far fa-trash-alt btnDelete" ></i></td>
      </tr>
      );
  }
}

export default TableHasp;
```

Code to pass data to child component from parent:

```
<div className="container">
        <table className="table table-striped">
        <thead className="thead-dark">
          <tr>
            <th scope="col">id</th>
            <th scope="col">Serial Number</th>
            <th scope="col">Soft</th>
            <th scope="col">Number of Keys</th>
            <th scope="col">Company</th>
            <th scope="col">City</th>
            <th scope="col">Contacts</th>
            <th scope="col">Date Created</th>
            <th scope="col">Edit</th>
            <th scope="col">Delete</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
         <tbody>
            {this.state.hasps.map((hasp, i) => 
            <TableHasp 
                 delEvent={this.deleteCurrentHaspInfo} 
                 modifyEvent={this.modifyCurrentHaspInfo}  
                 key={i} 
                 hasps={hasp} 
                 />)}
          </tbody>
         </table>
       </div>
```

And here a function where I need to pass an id:

```
deleteCurrentHaspInfo = (i) => {           
     if (confirm("Do you really want to delete this item from database?") === true){  //eslint-disable-line       
         if (prompt("Enter password:") === "123456") {
           axios.delete("/hasp/delete", {
            data: {
              _id: this.state.hasps[i]._id ///??????????
             // _id: this.state.hasps[5]._id    //this works
            }
           })
           .then((res) => {
            console.log(res.data);
           })
           .catch((err) => {
            console.log(err);
         })
         } else {
          alert("Wrong password!");
         }       
   } else {
     //alert("Delete Canceled!");
   }       
   }
```

Comment: Your child onClick function should be `onClick={() => this.props.delEvent(this.props.hasps._id)}` and the parent should be `delEvent={(id) => this.deleteCurrentHaspInfo(id)}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `this.props.hasps._id` in `onClick event` of  `TableHasp` component,

```
<td><i  onClick={() => this.props.delEvent(this.props.hasps._id)} className="far fa-trash-alt btnDelete" ></i></td>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can modify the `deleteCurrentHaspInfo` to be a higher order function, and make the first function take the `id`, using a closure to remember the variable.

It would look something like this

```
deleteCurrentHaspinfo = (id) = () => {
  // ...
  axios.delete("...", data: {_id: id})
}

// and in your TableHasp component 
delEvent={this.deleteCurrentHaspInfo(hasp._id)}
```

What this does is it that `deleteCurrentHaspInfo(hasp._id)` creates a new function that remembers the id via a closure.

Checkout MDN's article on closures: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures

And a quick intro to higher order funcitons in javascript: https://medium.freecodecamp.org/a-quick-intro-to-higher-order-functions-in-javascript-1a014f89c6b